# Rust: Use borrowing Fn parameter for body owned variables

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have:

- a data producer (e.g. `Rc<Vec<Data>>`)
- generic function (e.g. `fn assert_all(...)`) which transform generated data (e.g. `f`) before being processed (e.g. `assert_eq!(...)`) :

```rust
/// Pseudo-Rust code
fn assert_all<T,A,E>(producer: Rc<Vec<T>>, f: Fn(&T)->A, expecteds: Vec<E>) {
  let data = producer.as_ref().clone();
  let actuals: Vec<_> = data.iter().map(f).collect();
  assert_eq!(actuals, expecteds);
}
```

In order to tell Rust borrow checker transform function should bind generated lifetime from source, I have added an explicit lifetime:

```rust
fn assert_all<'inner, FN, ...>(...; f: FN) where
  FN: Fn(&'inner T) -> A,
  A: 'inner,
{
  // ...
}
```

However, I still have issue with borrow checker from function compilation saying, borrow outlive `data`.

Complete example code (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fa6d81657042e4516e04a1707f39cda0):

```rust
use std::{
    rc::Rc,
    fmt::Debug,
};

#[derive(Clone,Debug)]
struct Data {
    id: u32, 
    name: String,
}

impl Data {
    fn new(id: u32, name: &'static str) -> Self {
        Self {
            id,
            name: name.to_owned(),
        }
    }
    
    fn id(&self) -> u32 {
        self.id
    }
    fn name(&self) -> &String {
        &self.name
    }
}


fn assert_all<
    'inner,
    A,
    E,
    FN
>
(
    producer: Rc<Vec<Data>>,
    f: FN,
    expecteds: Vec<E>,
)
where
    A: 'inner + Debug + std::cmp::PartialEq<E>,
    E: Debug,
    FN: FnMut(&'inner Data) -> A,
{
    let data = producer.as_ref().clone();
    let actuals: Vec<_> = data.iter().map(f).collect();
    assert_eq!(actuals, expecteds);
}

fn main() {
    let data = Rc::new(vec![
        Data::new(0, "first"),
        Data::new(1, "second"),
    ]);
    assert_all(data, Data::name, vec!["first", "second"]);
}
```

Notes:

1. This is not my "real" code, just a minimum example illustrating my issue.
2. I know that if `f` just simply consumes ownerships and gives a new one, it solves the example. BUT NOT MY REAL CODE.

Comment: What is the problem with the first snippet (no lifetime explicitly specified)? It should work perfectly.

Comment: It shouldn't and it simply didn't :) https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d1b7a86deb2c0d660c55d7fcf5401c1c

As stated in my question, we need to tell A may be bound to Fn args.

Comment: The problem is that the trait bound `Fn(&T) -> A` doesn't allow `A` to depend on the (implicit) lifetime of the borrow `&T`, whereas it does for `Data::name`.

Comment: @jthulhu It's just what `'inner` does, no ? Or I missed something ?

Comment: @LoganMzz `'inner` just makes things worse, as the lifetime needs to be HRTB as it comes from a variable in the function.

Comment: I've run into a compiler bug ([#56556](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56556)) while trying to make it work... https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d822d938c23562f1dd52f87046f23e3a.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman TY for the try. I've not expected so much complex signature :)